# fadeIn vs fadeOut vs fadeTo

Tags: jquery, animation

What is the **difference** between `fadeIn` vs `fadeOut` vs `fadeTo` ?

Comment: The documentation should describe those methods: http://api.jquery.com Honestly, you should always read the documentation first before you ask any questions, 90% of your questions will be answered there.

Comment: @FelixKling - I agree with you in part, but often opening up a question like this for discussion finds hidden gotchas in the jQuery framework. eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045636/css-and-opacity-following-fadein-not-working

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) fades from an elements current opacity to 1.
[`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) fades from an elements current opacity to 0.
[`fadeTo`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) fades from an elements current opacity to a given opacity.

```
$('#myObject').fadeTo('fast', 0.5, function() {
    $('#myObject').fadeTo('fast', 0.8);
});
```

The above fades `myObject` from whatever opacity it has, to 0.5, which is 50% transparency, and after that, it fades up again to 20% transparency.

Comment: fadeIn() fadeOut() also affect the display property which is one of the main differences, fadeto() is able to fade to a certain degree of opacity not display.

Answer (score 13):

Short Answer:

- **fadeIn()** and **fadeOut()** control the `display` property, while animating fade.
- **fadeTo()** controls the `opacity` property, while animating fade.

---

Long Answer:

**fadeIn()** and **fadeOut()** are both designed to control the `display` property, just like show() and hide(), but animating only a fade in between.

Process of fadeIn()

- **Prep:** Set to `opacity:0`.
- **Process:** Set to `display:block`.
- **Process:** Gradually change to `opacity:1`.

Process of fadeOut()

- **Process:** Gradually change to `opacity:0`.
- **Process:** Set to `display:none`.

**fadeTo()** is meant to set the `opacity` property, while animating a fade in between.

Process of fadeTo()

- **Prep:** Set to `display: block`.
- **Process:** Set to `opacity: [$]`.

See the [breakdown of formulas, which make up fadeIn() and fadeTo()](http://jsfiddle.net/4EswC/1/) on JsFiddle.

**Update:**

Closer relatives of fadeIn() and fadeOut() are rather show() and hide().

**show()** and **hide()** are also meant to control the `display` property, just like fadeIn()and fadeOut(), but in addition, animate width and height in between.

Process of show()

- **Prep:** Set to `opacity:0`, `width:0`, `height:0`
- **Process:** Set to `display:block`
- **Process:** Gradually change to `opacity:1`, `width:[auto]`, `height:[auto]`

Process of hide()

- **Process:** Gradually change to `opacity:0`, `width:0`, `height:0`
- **Process:** Set to `display:none`.

Example:

Compare [behavior of fadeIn(), fadeOut(), fadeTo(), show() and hide()](http://jsfiddle.net/eN2BQ/) on JsFiddle.

Comment: i think this is the best answer as it specifies everything clearly.

Answer (score 2):

FadeIn.. Shows an element gradually

FadeOut .. Hides an element gradually

FadeTo .. Changes the opacity of an element to a given value

Answer (score -1):

I see only linguistic redundance here, since fadeTo fits all the use cases regardless.