# css() and opacity.. following fadeIn() not working

Tags: jquery

when I set opacity to 0 in css() the following fadeIn() doesn't work

if I set opacity to 1 the `loader` element is showed but there will of course not be any fading in..

```
loader.css({
        top : ($(window).height() - loader.height()) / 2+'px',
        left : ($(window).width() - loader.width()) / 2+'px',
        opacity : 0
    })
    .fadeIn(1000);
```

if I use display:none it works!?

```
loader.css({
        top : ($(window).height() - loader.height()) / 2+'px',
        left : ($(window).width() - loader.width()) / 2+'px',
        display : 'none'
    })
    .fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: What's the markup you're working with? How about a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using `fadeTo()`

```
loader.css({
    top : ($(window).height() - loader.height()) / 2+'px',
    left : ($(window).width() - loader.width()) / 2+'px',
    opacity : 0
})
.fadeTo(1000, 1);
```

Comment: This solves the problem, and if the OP wants to use the `fadeIn()`, hide the content via a `display: none` and it's sorted (as edited by the OP he/she knows it already).

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that jQuery only does functions like `fadeIn` if the element is not visible.  jQuery internally does [`$(this).is(':hidden')`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L142) to decide whether or not to run the animation.  The `hidden` filter clearly does not check to see if opacity is 0; it probably should.

The obvious solution is to set `display: none` as you have, or to call `hide()` before your call to `fadeIn()` if you are sure the element is hidden.

---

The other solution is to redefine the `hidden` filter to check for opacity:

```
jQuery.expr.filters.hidden = function(elem) {
    var width = elem.offsetWidth,
        height = elem.offsetHeight;

    return (width === 0 && height === 0) || (!jQuery.support.reliableHiddenOffsets && (elem.style.display || jQuery.css(elem, "display")) === "none" || (elem.style.opacity || jQuery.css(elem, 'opacity')) === "0");
};
```

Running `.is(':hidden')` will now check for opacity. [See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sku6P/).

---

I've filed [a bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9336) to cover this issue.

Answer (score 4):

.fadein() is used to show a hidden element, I dont know if it works with a opacity set to 0. Rather then opacity: 0 try display:none

edit: looks like you figured this out before my post went through