# jQuery click to fadeIn function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT: Changed hover to click.
EDIT2: Ended up putting a 0.6 opacity copy div below it and applied the same animation and fadeOut to it, then made it fadeToggle on click which is working, but lags a bit. Any more efficient solutions are welcome!
I have a click function for a div element that's not working. I want the click to restore opacity to a previously faded element (that part works fine) but after hours of trying it's just not happening.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).scroll(function() { 
    $(".circle-nav-element-sm").animate({
        left: '100px',
    }, "slow");
    $(".circle-nav-element-sm").fadeTo("slow", 0.6);
});
});

//Above part works fine.

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".circle-nav-element-sm").click(function() { 
        $(".circle-nav-element-sm").fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```

Can anyone see an obvious solution?

Comment: add html code .

Comment: @Lacomus Please share the code for click function.

Comment: Please create a fiddle link of your question.

Comment: Don't ask `please` in comments. if it is unclear, flag it. Or move on.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".circle-nav-element-sm").hover(function() { 
        $(".circle-nav-element-sm").fadeTo("fast",1);
    });
});
```

I'm guessing fadeTo doesn't work well with fadeIn and fadeout
[fadeIn vs fadeOut vs fadeTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311758/fadein-vs-fadeout-vs-fadeto)

Comment: Is there a way to make fadeOut only partial? I used fadeTo because I couldn't see an opacity option for the former.

Comment: fadeout and fadein work on the display property while fadeto works on the opacity property: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311758/fadein-vs-fadeout-vs-fadeto

Comment: Changed 'hover' to click, forgot I tried that before I copied the code. Using fadeTo with the 1 isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery fadeIn() method is used to fade in a hidden element.
At first make sure your circle-nav-element-sm div is hidden or not.If it is hidden it works for you if it is not please make sure it is hidden.